# How to include multiple entities with one many-to-many in between

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have 3 tier entities. `T <-> TI -> E also TI <- R` (where <-> is m..n and -> 1..m)

I need to select a single T with the TI, E and R

*without E it works:*

```
var t = dbContext.T
    .Include(i => i.TIs)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.I)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.R)
    .Single(i => i.Id == id);
```

**is it possible to include E without resorting to a for loop?**

**EDIT** thanks to both answers from Canolyb and EspressoBins, although not exactly working, but pushed me to the right track. So the working code is:

```
var t = dbContext.T
    .Include(i => i.TIs)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.I)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.R)

    .Include(i => i.TIs)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.I.Es)

    .Single(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: You have to show  how T and E  are related at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but to the best of my knowlesge includes can be cascaded like this if you need two ThenIncludes on the same relation.

```
var t = dbContext.T
  .Include(i => i.TIs)
  .ThenInclude(i => i.I)
  .Include(i => i.TIs)
  .ThenInclude(i => i.R)
  .Single(i => i.Id == id);
```

If this is not what you're looking for, it would benefit to see your Entity relations / fluent confiugation.

Answer (score 1):

I had to look at some old code of mine with a similar problem to solve, and forgive me if my relationship directions aren't exact to yours, but does this help you get any closer?
Without using the `.ThenInclude()`

```
            var result = dbContext.T
                .Include(t => t.TI)
                .Include(t => t.TI.E)
                .Include(t => t.TI.R)
                .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                .Single();
```

Comment: thank you. it did help. but i feel @Canolyb1 answer is a bit closer so i had to mark his answer (see my edit)